# Получить товары только с фото

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы. продукты и фото

Есть обычный запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM tm_product p
WHERE p.id_subcategory = $id_subcategory
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Который получает все товары из данной категории. Как в запросе написать что бы получать товары только с фото. Все фото находятся в отдельной таблице фото

Comment: Вам надо добавить название второй таблицы в `From`, а дальше связать их использую `join` или `where` по столбцам-ключам, и добавить условие на наличие фото.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tm_product p
INNER JOIN tm_photo ph ON p.id = ph.product_id
WHERE p.id_subcategory = $id_subcategory
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Вариант 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM tm_product p
WHERE p.id_subcategory = $id_subcategory
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
             FROM tm_photo ph 
             WHERE p.id = ph.product_id
           )
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Возможны и иные варианты.

Comment: супер спасибо, а как наоборот, получить фото у которых нету фото? при INNER JOIN tm_photo ph ON p.id != ph.product_id тупо зависает скрипт

Comment: @duddeniska Заменить INNER на LEFT условие в ON оставить в покое и в части where написать `and ph.id is null`. или использовать NOT EXISTS во втором примере.

Comment: Вы капец, гуру MySql

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tm_product AS p
LEFT JOIN
  tm_photos AS h
ON
  h.id_product = p.id
WHERE
  p.id_subcategory = $id_subcategory
ORDER BY
  p.id DESC
```

Comment: Левое связывание НИЧЕГО для решения задачи не даст. Можно, конечно, добавить `WHERE h.id_product IS NOT NULL` - но это просто превратит LEFT в INNER, проще сразу использовать именно его.

Comment: @Akina, почему? Ведь вернутся товары, у которых есть фотографии. А вот `WHERE h.id_product IS NOT NULL` явно бред какой-то

Comment: @Akina, въехал кажись, как вариант в моем запросе можно поменять таблицы местами, это идентично `INNER JOIN` будет

Comment: Нет, не идентично. Потребуется отсеивать дубликаты, если у товара более одной фотографии. Да и ресурсов запрос съест куда как больше.

Comment: А теперь поясните за то, что `левое связывание ничего не даст`? Оно не даст только в случае ОТСУТСТВИЯ условия `WHERE`, а в контексте данной задачи оно работает. И зачем отсеивать дубликаты, если нам нужны все фотки у всех товаров?

Comment: *поясните за то, что левое связывание ничего не даст?* Левое связывание возвращает ВСЕ записи из левой (tm_product) таблицы, вне зависимости от того, есть в правой (tm_photos) таблице записи или нет. *зачем отсеивать дубликаты, если нам нужны все фотки у всех товаров?* Перечитайте вопрос - автору нужны товары, а не их фото.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67994/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-akina).